# Can visual studio arrange my properties in alphabetical order?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Can visual studio automatically rearrange my class properties in alphabetical order?  I have a class with about 40 properties and I'd rather not do it by hand.

for instance I start with this class definition

```
public class User
{
    public string NameMiddle { get; set; }
    public string NameFirst { get; set; }
    public string IsActive { get; set; }
    public string NameLast { get; set; }
}
```

And run some feature you are about to tell me about and end up with this

```
public class User
{
    public string IsActive { get; set; }
    public string NameFirst { get; set; }
    public string NameLast { get; set; }
    public string NameMiddle { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This should be easy enough to do with an Visual Studio add-on.  This isn't possible out of the box though.

Comment: Do you know any free ones?

Comment: I use one of the many paid solutions, that offer this functionality, I suggest using one of those.  If you want it free you can always write the add-on yourself.  Should be easy enough to do.